# InvalidHeaderDeserialization Error After Finetune Training of LLM has Completed with Hugging Face Library

Tags: python, huggingface

I am trying to fine tune flan-t5-large to classify financial tweets. I'm running into an error message which occurs immediately after the model completes training. I'm unable to find existing posts in the context of the Hugging Face library. Given this, I'm having a very hard time debugging and resolving this error message, and am hoping that someone more familiar with the Hugging Face library could help.

```
import transformers
import textwrap
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer
import os
import sys
from typing import List

from peft import (
    LoraConfig,
    get_peft_model,
    get_peft_model_state_dict,
    prepare_model_for_int8_training,
)

import fire
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
import json

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(8, 6)})
sns.set(rc={'figure.dpi':100})
sns.set(style='white', palette='muted', font_scale=1.2)

DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
BASE_MODEL = "/Projects/llmtest1/models/flan-t5-large/"

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(
    pretrained_model_name_or_path=BASE_MODEL ,
    load_in_8bit=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained( 
    pretrained_model_name_or_path=BASE_MODEL)

tokenizer.pad_token_id = (0)
tokenizer.padding_side = "left"

data = load_dataset("ghbacct/twitter-financial-news-sentiment-classification")

def add_new_column(example):
    return {"instruction": "Detect the sentiment of the tweet."}

data = data.map(add_new_column)
data = data.rename_column("text", "input")
data = data.rename_column("label", "output")

CUTOFF_LEN = 256

def generate_prompt(data_point):
    return f"""Below is an instruction that describes a task, paired with an input that provides further context. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.  # noqa: E501
### Instruction:
{data_point["instruction"]}
### Input:
{data_point["input"]}
### Response:
{data_point["output"]}"""

def tokenize(prompt, add_eos_token=True):
    result = tokenizer(
        prompt,
        truncation=True,
        max_length=CUTOFF_LEN,
        padding=False,
        return_tensors=None,
    )
    if (
        result["input_ids"][-1] != tokenizer.eos_token_id
        and len(result["input_ids"]) < CUTOFF_LEN
        and add_eos_token
    ):
        result["input_ids"].append(tokenizer.eos_token_id)
        result["attention_mask"].append(1)

    result["labels"] = result["input_ids"].copy()
    return result

def generate_and_tokenize_prompt(data_point):
    full_prompt = generate_prompt(data_point)
    tokenized_full_prompt = tokenize(full_prompt)
    return tokenized_full_prompt

train_val = data["train"].train_test_split(
    test_size=200, shuffle=True, seed=42
)
train_data = (
    train_val["train"].shuffle().map(generate_and_tokenize_prompt)
)
val_data = (
    train_val["test"].shuffle().map(generate_and_tokenize_prompt)
)

LORA_R = 8
LORA_ALPHA = 16
LORA_DROPOUT= 0.05
LORA_TARGET_MODULES = ["q","v",]
BATCH_SIZE = 128
MICRO_BATCH_SIZE = 4
GRADIENT_ACCUMULATION_STEPS = BATCH_SIZE // MICRO_BATCH_SIZE
LEARNING_RATE = 3e-4
TRAIN_STEPS = 300
OUTPUT_DIR = "experiments"

model = prepare_model_for_int8_training(model)
config = LoraConfig(
    r=LORA_R,
    lora_alpha=LORA_ALPHA,
    target_modules=LORA_TARGET_MODULES,
    lora_dropout=LORA_DROPOUT,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
)
model = get_peft_model(model, config)

training_arguments = transformers.TrainingArguments(
    per_device_train_batch_size=MICRO_BATCH_SIZE,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=GRADIENT_ACCUMULATION_STEPS,
    warmup_steps=100,
    max_steps=TRAIN_STEPS,
    learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
    fp16=True,
    logging_steps=10,
    optim="adamw_torch",
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    save_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=50,
    save_steps=50,
    output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR,
    save_total_limit=3,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    report_to="tensorboard"
)

data_collator = transformers.DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(
    tokenizer, 
    pad_to_multiple_of=8, 
    return_tensors="pt", 
    padding=True)

trainer = transformers.Trainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=val_data,
    args=training_arguments,
    data_collator=data_collator
)
model.config.use_cache = False
old_state_dict = model.state_dict
model.state_dict = (
    lambda self, *_, **__: get_peft_model_state_dict(
        self, old_state_dict()
    )
).__get__(model, type(model))

    model.state_dict = (
        lambda self, *_, **__: get_peft_model_state_dict(self, old_state_dict())
    ).__get__(model, type(model))

trainer.train()
```

```
trainer = transformers.Trainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=val_data,
    args=training_arguments,
    data_collator=data_collator
)
model.config.use_cache = False
old_state_dict = model.state_dict
model.state_dict = (
    lambda self, *_, **__: get_peft_model_state_dict(
        self, old_state_dict()
    )
).__get__(model, type(model))


    model.state_dict = (
        lambda self, *_, **__: get_peft_model_state_dict(self, old_state_dict())
    ).__get__(model, type(model))

#peft_model = torch.compile(peft_model)

trainer.train()
#peft_model.save_pretrained(OUTPUT_DIR)
```

````
/home/nickjtay/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py:298: UserWarning: MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from torch.float32 to float16 during quantization
  warnings.warn(f"MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from {A.dtype} to float16 during quantization")
/home/nickjtay/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py:298: UserWarning: MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from torch.float32 to float16 during quantization
  warnings.warn(f"MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from {A.dtype} to float16 during quantization")
/home/nickjtay/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py:298: UserWarning: MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from torch.float32 to float16 during quantization
  warnings.warn(f"MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from {A.dtype} to float16 during quantization")
/home/nickjtay/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py:298: UserWarning: MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from torch.float32 to float16 during quantization
  warnings.warn(f"MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from {A.dtype} to float16 during quantization")
/home/nickjtay/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py:298: UserWarning: MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from torch.float32 to float16 during quantization
  warnings.warn(f"MatMul8bitLt: inputs will be cast from {A.dtype} to float16 during quantization")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SafetensorError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 18
     10 model.state_dict = (
     11     lambda self, *_, **__: get_peft_model_state_dict(
     12         self, old_state_dict()
     13     )
     14 ).__get__(model, type(model))
     16 #peft_model = torch.compile(peft_model)
---> 18 trainer.train()
     19 #peft_model.save_pretrained(OUTPUT_DIR)

File ~/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1530, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1528         hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   1529 else:
-> 1530     return inner_training_loop(
   1531         args=args,
   1532         resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1533         trial=trial,
   1534         ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1535     )

File ~/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1947, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1944     elif is_sagemaker_mp_enabled():
   1945         smp.barrier()
-> 1947     self._load_best_model()
   1949 # add remaining tr_loss
   1950 self._total_loss_scalar += tr_loss.item()

File ~/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2166, in Trainer._load_best_model(self)
   2164 if hasattr(model, "active_adapter") and hasattr(model, "load_adapter"):
   2165     if os.path.exists(best_adapter_model_path) or os.path.exists(best_safe_adapter_model_path):
-> 2166         model.load_adapter(self.state.best_model_checkpoint, model.active_adapter)
   2167         # Load_adapter has no return value present, modify it when appropriate.
   2168         from torch.nn.modules.module import _IncompatibleKeys

File ~/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py:647, in PeftModel.load_adapter(self, model_id, adapter_name, is_trainable, **kwargs)
    644         peft_config.inference_mode = not is_trainable
    645     self.add_adapter(adapter_name, peft_config)
--> 647 adapters_weights = load_peft_weights(model_id, device=torch_device, **hf_hub_download_kwargs)
    649 # load the weights into the model
    650 load_result = set_peft_model_state_dict(self, adapters_weights, adapter_name=adapter_name)

File ~/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/utils/save_and_load.py:270, in load_peft_weights(model_id, device, **hf_hub_download_kwargs)
    264             raise ValueError(
    265                 f"Can't find weights for {model_id} in {model_id} or in the Hugging Face Hub. "
    266                 f"Please check that the file {WEIGHTS_NAME} or {SAFETENSORS_WEIGHTS_NAME} is present at {model_id}."
    267             )
    269 if use_safetensors:
--> 270     adapters_weights = safe_load_file(filename, device=device)
    271 else:
    272     adapters_weights = torch.load(filename, map_location=torch.device(device))

File ~/Projects/llmtest1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safetensors/torch.py:308, in load_file(filename, device)
    285 """
    286 Loads a safetensors file into torch format.
    287 
   (...)
    305 ```
    306 """
    307 result = {}
--> 308 with safe_open(filename, framework="pt", device=device) as f:
    309     for k in f.keys():
    310         result[k] = f.get_tensor(k)

SafetensorError: Error while deserializing header: InvalidHeaderDeserialization
````